# rewrite the "?" and "=" into a forward slash /

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the `?` and `=` into a forward slash without have to rewrite the entire URL. I have a lot of trouble getting my head around .htaccess but is it possible to simply convert the `?` and `=` into `/` - this seems to me like a much more simple option. I have tried various methods but it ruins my .js and css files, so why cant i just rewrite those two characters into a /?

I eliminate the .php from all URLS:

```
# -FrontPage-
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# BEGIN GZIP
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript x-font/otf x-font/TTF x-font/eot
</ifmodule>
# END GZIP
```

Here is my URL I want to convert, but only the ? and =

```
www.example.com/search?store=hello
```

into

```
www.example.com/search/store/hello
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you searching for something as simple as this?

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /search.php?=$2
```

Place it above your current `RewriteRule` and it should work fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /search.php?=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue I have is this breaks the .css and .js files?

Comment: @SethCodes This should only break css/js files if they match the regex (start with "search/" then have at least one character before reaching another "/" then have at least one character that isn't a slash before ending). If you don't want to match periods either (in case it DOES clash with your js/css), you can change the last one to `([^/\.]+)` instead. This means "characters that aren't a slash, and aren't a period repeated 1 to infinity times".

Comment: `RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/([^/\.]+)$ /search.php?$1=$2` using this, it's fetching results but CSS and JS still being bitchy to me. If there an alternative way to stop the js/css from clashing? The images also clash.

Comment: @SethCodes What you're saying in `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f` is "any file that is REQUESTING FILE NAME plus ".php" that doesn't exist" which means that "script/main.js" would be evaluated as "script/main.js.php" and since that doesn't exist, try to open up `script/main.js.php`. Check my edit for something that should work.

Comment: Thank you, I end up using `<base href="">` as a valid solution too! Thank you for your time man!

Comment: You're welcome! You can also use `RewriteBase /`. :-)